# "Visually" constructible numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{E}^2$ ($\mathbb{E}^2$ denotes the Euclidean plane), an $S$-line is a straight line passing through $2$ different points of $S$ and an $S$-circle is a circle centered at a point of $S$ and passing through another point of $S$. A point $P \in \mathbb{E}^2$ is said to be **constructible** over $S$ if it is the transverse intersection of some $S$-lines and $S$-circles. Let $S_0=S$ and define $S_i$ ($i \ge 1$) to be the set of constructible points over $S_{i-1}$. Points in $S_i$ for some $i$ are called **iteratedly constructible** over $S$.

Now Let $S= \{ (-1,0),(1,0) \}$. The iteratedly constructible points over $S$ are called the constructible points $C$, and the lengths of segments connecting points in $C$ are called **non-negative constructible numbers $\mathfrak{C}$**. It is well-known that $\mathfrak{C} \cup -\mathfrak{C}$ forms a field which is the union of all iterated quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.

But why "lengths of segments"? Curves like circles are indeed constructible and their length is "visualized" on $\mathbb{E}^2$, e.g. the perimeter of the unit circle $2 \pi$. More precisely, we can define **visually constructible numbers** as follows:

We call a rectifiable curve $\gamma \subseteq \mathbb{E}^2$ connecting points in $C$ **visually constructible** if given any straight line $L$, the set $\gamma \cap L$ is iteratedly constructible over $C \cup L$ (note that $L$ need not be constructible over $C$). The lengths of all visually constructible curves will be called **non-negative visually constructible numbers $V \mathfrak{C}$**. By concatenation of translation of curves and homothety, it can be seen that $V \mathfrak{C}$ is a positive cone over $\mathfrak{C}$.

My questions will be concerned about the structure of $V \mathfrak{C}$:

1. Is it true that $V \mathfrak{C} \cup -V \mathfrak{C}$ is a vector space over $\mathfrak{C} \cup -\mathfrak{C}$?
2. $V \mathfrak{C}$ contains many transcendental numbers, unlike $\mathfrak{C}$. What do we know about these transcendental numbers? For example, does Euler's number $e$ belong to $V \mathfrak{C}$?

Comment: Are all numbers in $\mathfrak{VC}$ periods? It seems reasonable, but I can't immediately prove it

Comment: @CommandMaster I indeed have the belief that visually constructible curves must be piecewise algebraic.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to use a more readable font? That excessively caligraphic font is rather difficult to read (looks like DC? BC? RC? Not much like VC unfortunately). I'd suggest just plain VC. And secondly, you use the notation $\mathbb{E}$, but what does this mean?

Comment: In "lengths of segments ending in $C$", are the segments supposed to begin at the origin? \\ @JoelDavidHamkins, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461307/visually-constructibe-numbers#comment1196464_461307), I think that $\mathbb E^2$ is a relatively common replacement for $\mathbb R^2$ to emphasise that we are considering only its "Euclidean structure", i.e., lines and circles.

Comment: @LSpice No, the segment is not required to begin at the origin, but I think they give the same set of numbers.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I use fraktur characters to describe a set of **numbers** because in my post italic characters are already used to describe a set of **points**.

Comment: Sure, I expect there is method in the madness. I've seen textbooks full of  notation like this---but they are unreadable. I'd encourage you to find a meaningful but much simpler notation.

Comment: @LSpice By "ending in $C$", I mean **both ends** of the curve are in $C$.